# SVG text on a curve not showing in Firefox

Tags: css, svg, smil

This was working perfectly, then inexplicably Firefox began refusing to show the text.  The weird thing is if I open the image directly in firefox, rather than as part of a webpage it shows correctly.  What the heck!?

I've followed what's been on stackoverflow already, removing "preserve" from the text bits, but it made no difference.  So it must be something else.  I've tried removing the SMIL animations, text still doesn't show.  I tried removing the translation on the text group thinking perhaps it placed it outside the SVG's Viewbox, but that wasn't it.

The text loads perfectly when I right click on it in File explorer and load directly to Firefox, it works on Edge, IE, & Chrome.  So something must have changed in the SVG code to block it, to trip Firefox up when called from HTML.

Here's some code I'm using to embed it:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="imagesIndex/hero-images/gryffindor-lion-sq-animated-min.svg">
</object>
```

Here's the code pertaining to the text bits, the full file is too large to fit here :(, I'd love love love some help, it's so near finished:

```
  <g
     transform="translate(-0.00259344,-99.65596)"
     style="display:inline"
     id="layer1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="text overlay">
    <flowRoot
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:13.3333px;line-height:100%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="flowRoot1098"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion1100"><rect
           y="1371.9025"
           x="1179.4541"
           height="118.79394"
           width="243.24474"
           id="rect1102" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara1104" /></flowRoot>
    <g
       style="display:inline"
       id="g4034"
       transform="translate(1.0445758e-7,-3.174999)">
      <text
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:11.9944px;line-height:100%;font-family:Roboto;-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#3f424a;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fbb03b;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="text1065"><textPath
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:11.9944px;font-family:Roboto;-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto, Bold';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal"
           id="textPath3416"
           xlink:href="#path3399">THE QUILL IS MIGHTIER THAN THE WAND</textPath></text>
      <text
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:11.9944px;line-height:100%;font-family:Roboto;-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#3f424a;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fbb03b;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="text1069"><textPath
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:11.9944px;font-family:Roboto;-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto, Bold';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal"
           id="textPath3348"
           xlink:href="#path2336-8">UNLESS THE WAND IS THE DEATHSTICK</textPath></text>
      <path
         inkscape:transform-center-y="0.019669382"
         inkscape:transform-center-x="-0.0094046288"
         d="m 19.49303,222.28097 a 82.183404,82.183404 0 0 0 96.12163,65.33648 82.183404,82.183404 0 0 0 65.3365,-96.12162 82.183404,82.183404 0 0 0 -96.121652,-65.33648 82.183404,82.183404 0 0 0 -65.336478,96.12162 z"
         style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;stop-color:#000000"
         id="path2336-8" />
      <path
         id="path3399"
         style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.15261;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.178627;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;stop-color:#000000"
         d="M 26.753772,206.40088 A 73.400923,73.400923 0 0 1 100.75899,133.60927 73.400923,73.400923 0 0 1 173.55062,207.61448 73.400923,73.400923 0 0 1 99.545396,280.4061 73.400923,73.400923 0 0 1 26.753772,206.40088 Z" />
    </g>
  </g>
```

Here's the full SVG text of the file
[view-source:https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesIndex/hero-images/gryffindor-lion-sq-animated-min.svg](http://view-source:https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesIndex/hero-images/gryffindor-lion-sq-animated-min.svg)

Here's the full image itself
https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesIndex/hero-images/gryffindor-lion-sq-animated-min.svg

Comment: Have you tried tagging it with img source instead of an object?

Comment: The SMIL animation won't work.  I've found it does actually show, just dissappears when you resize the Firefox window.  I think Firefox must be a bit flaky with complex svgs.

Comment: That's possible. Was this made with Illustrator? I've had experiences with it outputting deprecated html values that might work on Chrome but are rejected by Safari or Firefox.

Comment: Inkscape.  It was robust at one point, just some unknown edits made it flaky.  I'll live with it.  I pray it works in Safari.  That'll have to do I think, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Create a minimal testcase and upload it to a [bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG) as an attachment.